# Is there a Stack Exchange site for recruiters? If not how do I start one?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have been in recruiting since 1987. The high turn-over rate in recruiting is due to training and mis-management.

Do you have howto sections for sales and recruiting? They are one and the same.

Comment: You can propose new site topics at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).